# How to solve a system of coupled Partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have following system of coupled Partial differential equations.
How can I solve the system by Mathematica.

\begin{align}   m_1\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial t^2}+A_1\frac{\partial ^2u_1(x,t)}{\partial x^4}+k(u_1-u_2)=F_1(t) \delta(x-x_1),  \end{align}
\begin{align}    m_2\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial t^2}-A_2\frac{\partial ^2u_2(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+k(u_2-u_1)=F_2(t)\delta(x-x_2).  \end{align}

In here,  $A_i, m_i, x_i$ and $k$ are constants where $i=1,2$ and $\delta$ is Dirac Delta function.

**Boundary conditions:**

$u_1(0,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(0,t)=u_1(l,t)=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}(l,t)=0$,

$u_2(0,t)=u_2(l,t)=0$

**Initial conditions:**

$u_i(x,0)=w_{i0}(x),$

$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x}(x,0)=y_{i0}(x)$ for $i=1,2.$

Since $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$ are unspecified (ungiven) functions, solutions $u_1,u_2$ which we seek will be depended on  $F_1(t)$ and $F_2(t)$.

**Code:**

```
PDE1 = m1*D[u1[x, t], {t, 2}] + A1*D[u1[x, t], {x, 4}] + 
    k*(u1[x, t] - u2[x, t]) == F1[t] DiracDelta[x - x1];
PDE2 = m2*D[u2[x, t], {t, 2}] - A2*D[u2[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
    k*(u2[x, t] - u1[x, t]) == F2[t] DiracDelta[x - x2];
```

Comment: Try with `DSolve` first if failed then try with `NDSolve`

Comment: Your equations contain the fourth derivative of $u_1$ with respect to $x$, but only the second derivative of $u_2$ with respect to $x$.  Is this intentional, or is it a typo?

Comment: No, it is not a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one boundary condition. ( I added) But it has just 4 initial conditionals.

Comment: Take the Laplace transform in `t` of the equations, leaving two coupled equations in `x`, which can be solved either numerically or symbolically, depending on the details of `w[x]` and `y[x]`.  Then, perform the inverse Laplace transform.  This last part could be difficult.